# How can System.out.format prevent a deadlock?

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock

I've found that including a call to System.out.format in the classic [Java Deadlock Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) will prevent deadlock from occurring, and I can't figure out why.

The code below is the same as that of the tutorial, with the addition to `main` of `System.out.format("Hi, I'm %s...no deadlock for you!\n\n", alphonse.getName());`

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;

        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!\n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }

        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!\n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");

        System.out.format("Hi, I'm %s...no deadlock for you!\n\n", alphonse.getName());

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Hi, I'm Alphonse...no deadlock for you!

Alphonse: Gaston has bowed to me!
Gaston: Alphonse has bowed back to me!
Gaston: Alphonse has bowed to me!
Alphonse: Gaston has bowed back to me!
```

Removing the offending line results in the usual deadlock:

```
Alphonse: Gaston has bowed to me!
Gaston: Alphonse has bowed to me!
... deadlock ...
```

Is the call to System.out.format somehow changing the way the threads acquire the intrinsic locks on the objects?

Update:

I was able to get the system to deadlock again just by changing where I start the threads in the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
    final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");

    System.out.format("Hi, I'm %s...no deadlock for you!\n\n", alphonse.getName());

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

This begs the question about how we can get greater insight into how the thread scheduler behaves, but I'll save that for a different day.

Comment: When you add that line, the first thread is done before the main thread starts the second thread.

Comment: But that's only by coincidence on one particular processor and scheduler.  There's still no guarantee that deadlock won't occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not really remove the *deadlock* but rather (because of some internal JVM reason) changed that timing of the threads so that one of the threads enters `bowBack()` *before* the other calls `bow()`. 
Just put in `bow`: `sleep(1000)` and your deadlock will reappear.

Note that deadlock does not *always* happen, only when the threads are in *lucky* timing. In this case, deadlock will happen when both threads enter `bow` and before any of them call `bowBack`

...
And *"some internal JVM reason"* can be the following:

In your case there are actually three threads: the one executing *main*, *t1*, and *t2*.
The reason why putting *print* hides the deadlock can be that the thread scheduler decided that `main` still had work to do, i.e. flushing the io buffers, and therefore let *main* continue after starting *t1* and before starting t2. If you are on a dual-core cpu, only `main` and `t1` would run, but `t2` would wait, since `print` is a slow operation. Context switching would take some more time, and *t1* would finish before *t2* could start...so no deadlock would happen. But that does not mean that if you run the program again deadlock won't happen.

If you want to play, create a `queue` and push tokens (thread names) in that queue, then `join` your threads in main. After they finish, print the queue content and you can observe the timing of the threads.

Answer (score 0):

`format()` and writing to a console are usually expensaive operations. I guess its execution is altering the timing on which the threads are started, so that the second thread starts so late that it does not interfere with the first.