# Deadlock - how does it happen in this example?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, synchronized

can anyone explain:

1. why do we  get a deadlock?
2. how can Gaston enter function bow before Alphonse exit that function? (it should return from function `bowBack()` in order to exit the function `bow()` - or)?

This is the output I get - and then program is stuck!

> Alphonse: Gaston  has bowed to me!
>
> Gaston: Alphonse  has bowed to me!

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider playing some [Deadlock Empire](https://deadlockempire.github.io/) to get a feel for detecting race conditions.

Answer (score 23):

The `synchronized` block / method is synchronized to `this`, that is the object instance the block / method is called. (For `static` "object instance" is to be replaced with "class instance".)

That is your 2 objects get synchronized to themselves, not a common object.

Try something like this:

```
public class Deadlock {
   static class Friend {
      private final String name;
      public Friend(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }
      public String getName() {
         return this.name;
      }
      public void bow(Friend bower) {
         synchronized (getClass()) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s  has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
         }
      }
      public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
         synchronized (getClass()) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final Friend alphonse = new Friend("Alphonse");
      final Friend gaston = new Friend("Gaston");
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
      }).start();
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
      }).start();
   }
}
```

Comment: or you can keep the methods as they are `synchronized` but call `bowBack()` inside a thread : `new Thread() {
    public void run() {
     bower.bowBack(Friend.this);
    };
   }.start();` this way `bow()` will end and unlock `this`, `bowback()` can run normally

Comment: what did you mean by " that is the object instance the block / method is called"?

Comment: The methods are synchronized to the instance of the object they are called on. In this case these are instances of your `Friend` class.

Comment: you mean that many objects can enter synchronized function parallel because it's a different lock for each object?

Comment: @Ohad That is what he is trying to say. You can also read my updated answer; I tried to make that aspect more clear.

Answer (score 9):

Thread 1:
`alphonse` instance gets locked from `alphonse.bow(gaston);` which prints a line and then calls `gaston.bowBack()` (but `gaston` is locked from Thread 2 due to synchronized `bow()` instance called on it below)

Thread 2:
`gaston` instance gets locked from `gaston.bow(alphonse);` which prints a line and then calls `alphonse.bowBack()`(but `alphonse` is locked from Thread 1 due to synchronized `bow()` instance called on it)

So they're both waiting for the release and cannot exit `bow()` method, hence the Deadlock

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the *usage* of *synchronized* is wrong. The oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) nicely states:

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the **same** object to interleave.

As explained by the other answer: the code shown in the example **does** not use a "common lock" (synchronized methods on two different objects do not affect the "other" method call).

Beyond that: as soon as you **remove** those `System.out.format()` calls - your program can (will most often) **not** run into a deadlock.

Or: put a `println()` in your main **before** you start the threads - again, the program will **not** deadlock.

In other words: printing to the console is extremely time consuming. Therefore this affects the **timing** of your threads dramatically! What happens here is that *most* of the time is spent for those console output actions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450547/how-can-system-out-format-prevent-a-deadlock) for a similar question that even uses the same names ;-)

Answer (score 6):

What happens in your example:

1. Thread Alphonse is acquiring the lock to Alphonse by entering the function `bow`.
2. Thread Gaston is acquiring the lock to Gaston by entering the function `bow`.
3. Thread Alphonse is requesting the lock to Gaston to enter the function `bowBack` but that lock is currently held by Thread Gaston, so Alphonse is forced to wait.
4. Thread Gaston is requesting the lock to Alphonse to enter the function `bowBack` but that lock is currently held by Thread Alphonse, so Gaston is forced to wait.

Dead-lock.

Why this is happening:

A `synchronized` function is syntactic sugar for `synchronized(this) { ... }` So the class above could also be written like this:

```
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (this) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
}

public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (this) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}
```

`this` in this example is however the instance of the class, so each instance has it's individual lock. If you want to lock on the same object in all instances of a class, you need to lock on a static object like this:

```
protected static final Object STATIC_LOCK = new Object();

public void bow(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (STATIC_LOCK) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
}

public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
    synchronized (STATIC_LOCK) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has bowed back to me!%n", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}
```

Since this `LOCK` object is static, both threads will now lock on the *same* object, and therefore correctly lock out each other. Notice the keyword `final` which is strongly recommended in this case, because otherwise what synchronized locks on could change during execution (by bugs or oversights in your code), which would put you back into the dead-lock situation for the exact same reason as above.