# Understanding deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand how to create a deadlock from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html.

Instead of copy and pasting the sample code, I chose to write it by myself.

The last line in the link says "neither block will ever end because each thread is waiting for the other to exit bow" but never mentions about System.out.format.

I then wrote the below code and it never entered deadlock

```
public class DeadlockTest {
  static class Resource {
    public synchronized void test1(Resource r) {
      System.out.print("test1");
      r.test2();
    }
    public synchronized void test2() {
      System.out.print("test2");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String... a) {
    final Resource r1 = new Resource();
    final Resource r2 = new Resource();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        r1.test1(r2);
      }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        r2.test1(r1);
      }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

So I tried to compare line by line and found that only the print statement is wrong. Instead of using System.out.format I used System.out.print. So the code never ran in to a dead lock situation. I then changed it to System.out.format and I was able to simulate a dead lock.

I even copied the example code from the link, changed the format statement to print/println and it was not entering deadlock.

Can anyone please explain how to exactly create a deadlock?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450547/how-can-system-out-format-prevent-a-deadlock ... similar question, might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code to test it. It indeed ran fine.

Only when I added a `Thread.sleep(100)` or the `String.format` in `test1`, it blocked. It seems as if your "work" method (`print`) is too fast. Before the second thread can cause the block by calling `test1`, the first thread is already finished with `test2`.

To stay in the tutorials example: Your threads did not in fact "bow at each other **at the same time**", but only "**very quickly after one another**". Make the bowing a little slower and you increase the **chances** of them bowing at the same time (still not guaranteed, e.g. if the system takes longer to schedule the second thread).